# python plot error bar with categorical x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data

```
  X       Y
  1      0.1
  1      0.2
  1      0.3
  2      0.3
  2      0.4
  2      0.5
  .
  .
  .
```

where X takes value from 1 to 5 and Y takes any real number. I would like to plot the error bar where the x-axis is the possible values of X -- 1 to 5, where the error bar represents the standard deviation of Y given X and also the mean of Y given X.

Comment: You could try seaborn's `sns.barplot(data=..., x='X', y='Y', ci='sd')`

Comment: Or `sns.pointplot(data=..., x='X', y='Y', ci='sd')`